# How to change the sender while sending an email using bash

Tags: bash

This is what I am using

```
/bin/mailx -s "$SUBJECT1" "$EMAIL" < "$EMAILMESSAGE"
```

Since I dont have access to a particular machine I am using my friends credential to login and I want my name as the sender. how should i do it?

Answer (score 0):

Use -r to specify the "From Address"

```
/bin/mailx -r <replyemail> -s "$SUBJECT1" "$EMAIL" < "$EMAILMESSAGE"
```

Comment: the -r flag hasn't been around for a while.

Comment: -r shows up in the man page and --help on Cent6.4, command executed fine and I received the email as expected with the correct sender.   mailx -V 
12.4 7/29/08   
    
"mailx -r cmontanaro@shtuff.it -s 'Test Email' cmontanaro@shtuff.it < testemail"

Comment: guess it depends on the *nix version. BSD/OSX version's don't have it, doesn't appear to be in ubuntu either.

Answer (score 0):

Use email client like mutt to login on your email account. Or are you talking about internal emails on this machine only?

Answer (score 0):

you can try this

```
export REPLYTO=me@myemail.com
/bin/mailx -aFrom:me@myemail.com "$SUBJECT1" "$EMAIL" < "$EMAILMESSAGE"
```

to add the from header to the message if your copy of mailx has -a

or

```
/bin/mailx -s "$SUBJECT" "$EMAIL" -- -f me@myemail.com <  "$EMAILMESSAGE"
```

the `--` should just pass the -f along to the underlying mail program.